# What is the best way to use Amazon SSL certificate in Load balancing or Cloud Front

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

Which one is better to install Amazon SSL certificate in Cloudfront or in Load balncer

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

As you might already know, Cloudfront is a CDN and will deliver your content closer to end-consumers who access the content (using AWS Edge network). If you don't require that or your content needs to be delivered fast only to regional consumers (where your load balancer is in) then you don't have to use Cloudfront.

In other words, you could have SSL added at either Cloudfront or at the ALB depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For CloudFront, you need to get a ACM cert in us-east-1 and for load balancers , it should be in the same region as your load balancer.